# Can loading of a large Excel file using XLWorkBook be aborted?

Tags: c#, vb.net, abort, closedxml

I am employing XLWorkBook (Closed.XML) to open Excel files.  However, in the case of a large file, I may want to abort the loading and transition to .csv, SQL, or Access for input.  Therefore, is there a way to abort the loading process?  The line on which the process hangs up for very large files is mentioned in the code below.

```
    Dim workbook = New XLWorkbook(filename)
    Dim rows = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().RowsUsed()  'large files hang here
    Dim cols = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().ColumnsUsed()
```

Comment: If you have multiple input types, why not always load from SQL?

Comment: What do you use `rows` for? Is it vital?

Comment: @Magnetron: users may not have SQL inputs.

Comment: @Caius Jard: Need #rows & #cols for dimensioning arrays.  Is there a way to stuff an XLWorkBook into a DataTable perhaps, and then pull #rows, #cols from that?

Comment: Erm.. that kinda implies that after loading it into memory once(closed xml might do it?) you load it in again(transfer to another memory based device), and if this is timing out then the spreadsheet could be huge? What is the destination of this data? Could it be streamed to there?

Comment: I asked because you said that if the file is too big, you switch to another input. If, as you said, the user may not have SQL inputs, how are you transitioning to other input? Also, if I recall correctly, [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) library read by stream, so it handles large files better, try it out. Also, it can read the data to a `DataSet`

Comment: @Caius Jard: Destination is arrays for math processing.

Comment: @Magnetron: transitioning by using other methods to read in text, .csv, Access, or SQL.  Thx for the tip on ExcelDataReader.

Comment: @Magnetron, question is regarding ExcelDataReader, can the load process be aborted?  Doubt it, so back at square one.

Answer (score 1):

For a very large Excel file, instead of using the Closed.XML commands `RowsUsed()` and `ColumnsUsed()` to pull rows and columns from the worksheet and then fill the array like this:

```
     rows = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().RowsUsed() 
     cols = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().ColumnsUsed() 

     ReDim x(rows.Count, cols.Count) 
     For Each xrow In rows
        Dim rowNumber = xrow.RowNumber()
        For Each xcol In cols
           Dim colNumber = xcol.ColumnNumber()
           x(rowNumber, colNumber) = xrow.Cell(colNumber).Value
        Next
     Next xrow
```

you can loop through the rows and columns and insert a [coordinated cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) using tokens (since Abort.Thread is obsolete).

First, declare a public cancellation token:

```
     Public cts As CancellationTokenSource = New CancellationTokenSource
```

Next, to cancel a threaded method, set the cancellation, perhaps in a "Cancel" button somewhere on a Form:

```
     cts.Cancel()
```

Then, inside the threaded method, place a test for whether or not the token was cancelled, and if so, exit the method:

```
     Dim numrows, numcols As Integer
     numrows = 0
     numcols = 0  
     For Each row As IXLRow In workbook.Worksheet(1).Rows()
        If cts.token.IsCancellationRequested = True Then 
           Exit Sub
        Else
           numrows += 1
        End If
              
     Next
     For Each col As IXLColumn In workbook.Worksheet(1).Columns
        If cts.token.IsCancellationRequested = True Then 
           Exit Sub
        Else
           numcols += 1
        Endif
     Next
```

If the user has not aborted this threaded method, then dimension the array first, and then fill it with cell values:

```
     ReDim x(numrows, numcols) 
     For i = 1 To numrows
       For j = 1 To numcols
         x(i, j) = workbook.Worksheet(1).Cell(i, j).Value
       Next
     Next
```